# Subclassing an OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a simple Calendar application in android, mostly for personal learning as I am new to Android (and Java for that matter).

Basically, it's a ListView showing the current days of the month that, when clicked, opens a dialog asking for an event description.

Obviously, this dialog has an OK button that when clicked should update the ListView with the input from the EditText.

However, I'm having trouble getting the OnClickListener for the OK button to work, no matter what I try, I get a NullPointerException on the line where I set it.

```
public class SimpleCalendar extends ListActivity {

    public static Context appContext;
    public static int nMonthChoice = CalendarIO.myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    private static ArrayAdapter aAd;
    private static String[] ArrayOfDays;
    final private static String[] dayNames = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    Dialog userInput;
    int currentDay;
    EditText dialogInput;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        appContext = this;
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        CalendarIO.initCalendar(tv);

        CalendarIO.myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, nMonthChoice);
        updateMonth();
        aAd = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.main, ArrayOfDays);

        setListAdapter(aAd);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                LinearLayout dialogLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dLL);
                currentDay = position + 1;
                dialogInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dET);

                userInput = new Dialog(appContext);
                userInput.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                userInput.setTitle("New Event");

                Button dBtn = new Button(appContext);
                dBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                        userInput.dismiss();
                        CalendarIO.myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay);
                        SimpleCalendar.updateMonth();
                        CalendarIO.CalendarEvents.put(CalendarIO.myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), dialogInput.getText());
                        SimpleCalendar.aAd = new ArrayAdapter(appContext, R.layout.main, ArrayOfDays);
                        setListAdapter(SimpleCalendar.aAd);

        }});
                dialogLayout.addView(dBtn);
                userInput.show();

            }
        });

    }

    public static void updateMonth() {
        int nCounter, nDaysInMonth;
        String sCurrentEvent;
        String currentDay;

        nDaysInMonth = CalendarIO.myCalendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        ArrayOfDays = new String[nDaysInMonth];

        for (nCounter = 0; nCounter < nDaysInMonth; nCounter++) {


            CalendarIO.myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, nCounter + 1);
            sCurrentEvent = (String) CalendarIO.CalendarEvents.get(
                    CalendarIO.myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

            currentDay = dayNames[CalendarIO.myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1];

            ArrayOfDays[nCounter] =
                    currentDay + ", " + MonthView.monthNames[nMonthChoice]
                    + " " + (nCounter + 1);

            try {
                if (!sCurrentEvent.equals("")) {
                    ArrayOfDays[nCounter] += ("\t- " + sCurrentEvent + "\n");
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {//don't do anything}
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I know the code is a little unreadable but I hope you'll bear through it. I'm also planning on cleaning up some of the global variables later..

Anyway, these are the main two methods for input. updateMonth() turns a hash map from my CalendarIO class into a String Array, and of course, onCreate is my main Activity method.

When I run it, ADB gives me:

```
17:51:53.814    22161   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
17:51:53.814    22161   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.NullPointerException
17:51:53.814    22161   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at 
org.me.simplecalendar.SimpleCalendar$1.onItemClick(SimpleCalendar.java:80)
```

Line 80 is `dialogLayout.addView(dBtn);`

This was my latest attempt: trying to add a newly created button to my XML defined LinearLayout.

I've also tried having the button defined in XML and just adding a listener to it. That also complains about an NPE.

Also, I've tried defining the listener in XML as well and pointing it to a method in the class, but it throws an error saying that it can't find my method in the ComponentInfo class, which is a little bizarre - but I'm sure it's just something I haven't learned yet.

I'm at the end of my attempts.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. In the end, I decided to use an AlertDialog with a custom View.
I wasn't aware that they supported custom views at first (I'm new to this :P). The calendar works great now!

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though your null pointer reference could be your `dialogLayout`. This is because you are calling `findByViewId` before calling `SetContentView`. You need to call `SetContentView` before calling any `findByViewId` methods. You should ideally do this at the beginning of the `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 1):

Dialog buttons use DialogInterface.OnClickListener not View.OnclickListener

Comment: yep, well, it you have a button in a view (e.g. a custom layout used in a dialog) that is used by a dialog the that will use View.OnclickListener but if you have buttons at the bottom (out) they use DialogInterface.OnClickListener